# Cassandra CorruptedSSTableException

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm using DSE 5.0 on 4 nodes and the cluster is working properly for a longtime and suddenly I got this error and I can't execute queries against the "documents" table

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:13] 2017-07-15 16:34:46,632  CassandraDaemon.java:205 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:13,1,main]
org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: Corrupted: /cassandraData/documents/documents-a693bab05fa911e6b6ee3565c1b99c8e/mc-406438-big-Data.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.computeNext(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:112) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.computeNext(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:30) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.LazilyInitializedUnfilteredRowIterator.computeNext(LazilyInitializedUnfilteredRowIterator.java:95) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.LazilyInitializedUnfilteredRowIterator.computeNext(LazilyInitializedUnfilteredRowIterator.java:32) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:369) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.advance(MergeIterator.java:189) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$ManyToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:158) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:481) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIterators$UnfilteredRowMergeIterator.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIterators.java:341) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseRows.hasNext(BaseRows.java:129) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex$Builder.build(ColumnIndex.java:111) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnIndex.writeAndBuildIndex(ColumnIndex.java:52) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.append(BigTableWriter.java:149) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.append(SSTableRewriter.java:125) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.MaxSSTableSizeWriter.realAppend(MaxSSTableSizeWriter.java:88) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.append(CompactionAwareWriter.java:109) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:183) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:78) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:60) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:263) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error building row with data deserialized from /cassandraData/documents/documents-a693bab05fa911e6b6ee3565c1b99c8e/mc-406438-big-Data.db - chunk length 65536, data length 333982306.
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserializeRowBody(UnfilteredSerializer.java:467) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserialize(UnfilteredSerializer.java:377) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableSimpleIterator$CurrentFormatIterator.computeNext(SSTableSimpleIterator.java:87) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableSimpleIterator$CurrentFormatIterator.computeNext(SSTableSimpleIterator.java:65) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.doCompute(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:123) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableIdentityIterator.computeNext(SSTableIdentityIterator.java:100) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTreeSearchIterator.next(BTreeSearchIterator.java:93) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset(Columns.java:604) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Columns$Serializer.deserializeSubset(Columns.java:500) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredSerializer.deserializeRowBody(UnfilteredSerializer.java:450) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.8.1293.jar:3.0.8.1293]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

"nodetool repair" always failed.

queries on this table sometimes failed with the following error:

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

How can I repair this table "documents"?